# Virtual Network Interface

Tags: networking, virtualization, proxy

Recently I configured my Ubuntu in enterprise where it is used Windows machines as usual. Problem is that proxy settings are obtained through domain settings. And this is not relevant to my Linux machine. To configure the proxy is annoying, especially when the domain controller needs to change the password every 15 days and I have to change it in some files (apt.conf, netbeans, maven etc.).

Is there any way to create a virtual network card which will work through proxy (HTTP, HTTPS, DNS will be enough for me) and requests from my machine will be routed through this NIC? (Something like middlebox)

Comment: The squid approach is general.  There is an easier way in the special circumstance where  you can add a new IP address and you either don't care about others accessing that IP address as you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of configuring every app with the proxy setting, setup a **transparent proxy** using a proxy server like *squid proxy*. After configuring the setting all the apps are redirected to squid automatically by the OS.

Following link will help you to setup a *transpaent proxy*

[Linux: Setup a transparent proxy with Squid in three easy steps](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-setup-transparent-proxy-squid-howto.html)